# Turn list of strings into list of floats (python)

Tags: python, list

I wrote the following function:

```
def read_coordinates(filename):
    invoerfile = open(filename)
    lines = invoerfile.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        seperate_coordinate_rows = line.split("=")
        for seperate_coordinate_row in seperate_coordinate_rows:
            row = seperate_coordinate_row.split()
            print row
```

which gives me these lists:

```
['5,4', '4,5', '8,7']
['6,3', '3,2', '9,6', '4,3']
['7,6']
['9,8']
['5,5', '7,8', '6,5', '6,4']
```

What do I need to add to this function to get lists with floats as output?

Comment: Can you post an example of the input?

Comment: If you post a sample of your input, someone here can possible come up with a better solution than this.

Comment: Instead of `['7,6']`, it should be `[7.6]`. Is this what you want? Or should it be `[7,6]`?

Comment: Iw want 7.6, the answer I accepted was exactly what is was looking for

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this:

```
row = map(lambda x: float(x.replace(',','.')), row)
```

The above will return a generator in Python 3.x, which may or may not suit your needs. If you need an actual list, you have two options:

```
# Convert the generator to a list (bad option)
row = list(row)

# Or use a list comprehension
row = [float(x.replace(',','.')) for x in row]
```

Comment: This will return a generator in Python 3.x

Comment: Why not use a list comprehension here? `[float(x.replace(',', '.')) for x in row]`. It'll be faster than the `map` (no stack push), and work the same in both Python 2 and 3.

Comment: Fixed it, although I don't think the OP is using Python 3.x, nor will he care about the _really tiny_ performance improvement of using listcomp vs maps.

Answer (score 0):

Put this inside your inner for loop.

```
row = [float(x.replace(',', '.') for x in row]
```

Answer (score 0):

Map your values to `float()`:

```
row = map(float, seperate_coordinate_row.replace(',', '.').split())
```

`map()` calls the first argument for each value in the second value, effectively returning a list of float values.

The `.replace()` here is needed to turn your format to one that `float()` recognizes.

Demo:

```
>>> line = '5,4 4,5 8,7'
>>> map(float, line.replace(',', '.').split())
[5.4, 4.5, 8.7]
```

If you are using Python 3, or just want to use a list comprehension anyway, use:

```
[float(item.replace(',', '.') for item in seperate_coordinate_row.split()]
```

Here the `.replace()` is applied to each split item instead.

Comment: You'd first need to replace "," with ".".

Comment: Shouldnt we use `locales` to process this data?

Answer (score 0):

To make sure you get a list it's best to use a list comprehension, since `map` doesn't return a list in Python3

```
row = [float(x.replace(",", ".")) for x in seperate_coordinate_row.split()]
```

Answer (score 0):

replace the last two lines with

```
row = [float(item.replace(',', '.')) for item in seperate_coordinate_row.split()]
print row
```